# Write to google docs from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-docs-api, omnibox

I am trying to make a chrome extention that will take text from the omnibox, open a new google doc, and paste the text into that doc. I already have a link that creates new google docs, but how can I put text into from here?
I know I can use:

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(
  function(text) {
                   var newURL = "https://docs.google.com/document/create?hl=en";
                   chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
  }
  );
```

To handle the text typed into the omnibox, and open a new doc, it's just the rest of it I can't quite figure out.

EDIT: after some more searching I have found that there is a Google Drive API, I'm not sure if I can use it in an extension or really how to use it.

Answer (score -2):

The Google Drive API is the correct approach, and you can use it from an Extension. There is an example of a Drive extension here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/gdrive